# How to assign a series of variables with similar name

Tags: javascript

I declared six variables:

```
let L1, L2, L3, R1, R2, R3
```

and then I want to assign these six variables with the same value:

```
L1 = "something";
L2 = "something";
L3 = "something";
R1 = "something";
R2 = "something";
R3 = "something";
```

There must be a shorter way to do this right? I want to do it in a loop, because in this example we only have six variables, but in fact I have a lot of them.

Comment: `bubbles.forEach((value, key) => {
   bubbles[key] = value;
})` would be how to assign.

Comment: *"...I really don't just use arr[0], arr[1].."* Use Object Literals you heard of them, right?

Comment: Could you include what you are actually doing with all the variables? Then maybe someone could offer up a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main way I see you being able to accomplish this is using an object (as others have already pointed out). You will still need to instantiate all the variables initially using the long-form syntax; but then you will be able to use a "for in" loop to actually assign all of the necessary values:

```js
let something = {
  L1: null,
  L2: null,
  L3: null,
};

for (let prop in something){
  something[prop] = 1;
};

console.log(something);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an object instead?

```
const bubbles = {
  bubbleL1,
  bubbleL2,
  bubbleL3,
  bubbleR1,
  bubbleR2,
  bubbleR3
};
```

If you want to use array methods on it, you can extract an array of the values from the object with `Object.values`.

For your new question, you can fill an array with values, then destructure:

```js
const [L1, L2, L3, R1, R2, R3] = new Array(6).fill('something');
console.log(L1);
console.log(R3);
```

Answer (score 1):

I will directly answer your question, even though I think you shouldn't do that, you should think in a more "javascript" way of doing this.

That said:

```
const value = "something";
const numberOfVars = 100;
for( let i=0; i< numberOfVars; i++)
    eval( "L"+ i + " = value" );
```

That would create the variables L0 to L99 with the value "something" inside. You could do that for any name, be it R, L or any string which is a valid javascript variable name.

Comment: Even though my answer is the only one until now which actually does what you asked for, my recommendation would be to go with [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) as other answers have already shown.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give each variable its own name, but also have them grouped together so that you can use a blanket statement to set all their values, you got two  easy options:

Option 1:
Use an array. An array will not allow you to name your variables, but they will be auto-assigned "names" according to their position (index) in the array. For example, if you made an array of the following values: "Cookie", "Money", and "Nothing." then they would be assigned numbers to reference them by, "Cookie" would be named "0", "Money" would be named "1", "Nothing." will be named "2" and so on... Here's an example of what an array looks like:

```
var nameOfArray = ["value1","value2","value3"];
```

and to access the value of an array, simply use that value's index:

```
nameOfArray[0]
```

(^^^ This would return "value1" ^^^)

So, if you think about it, that makes arrays very for-loop-friendly, so therefor this example looks very simple. Simply use the following to assign every variable in your array to the same value:

```
for(let i = 0;i < nameOfArray.length;i++){
    nameOfArray[i] = "Whatever value I want.";
}
```

Option 2:
Use an object. An object is basically a group of named variables. The name of the variable is called the "key" and the value of the variable is called the "value". This is usually called a "key/value pair" For example:

```
var nameOfObject = {
    variable1: "value1",
    variable2: "value2",
};
```

Where "variable2" is a key, and "value2" is a value.

Then you can access each variable inside the object using simple dot or bracket notation.
Dot notation: `nameOfObject.variableName`
Bracket notation: `nameOfObject["variableName"]`

Setting all variables inside an object to the same value can be tricky. To do so, I usually use a for loop that iterates through all the keys in an object, and sets their values. In order to do so, you will first need to collect all the names of all the keys in the object. I simply use: `Object.keys(nameOfObject)` then I iterate through that array and assign each variable a value:

```
const objectKeyNames = Object.keys(nameOfObject);

for(let i = 0;i < objectKeyNames.length;i++){
    nameOfObject[objectKeyNames[i]] = "Whatever I want to set it to.";
}
```

And it's that simple! All variables inside the object will be set to "Whatever I want to set it to."

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you are looking for a map rather than a list.

if you declare an object

```
var bubbles = {}
```

you can then access items by name

```
bubbles['bubbles1'] = 'something';
```

you can also loop through the items like a list later if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

you can assign using left hand assignment like this:
`let L1 = L2 = L3 = R1 = R2 = R3 = "something";`
however that will cause a scope issue.
it would be better to declare then assign like

```
let L1, L2, L3, R1, R2, R3;
L1 = L2 = L3 = R1 = R2 = R3 = "something";`
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have like hundred variables that are not in fact parts of object?

Like `let R1,R2,R3,L1,L2,L3` could be volume {left, right} for 3 audio track.

So you can write

`let tracks = [{ right : 0, left : 0}, { right : 0, left : 0},  { right : 0, left : 0}]`

L1 will become `tracks[0].left` and R3 will become `tracks[2].right`

With 100 tracks?

```
let tracksCount = 100;
let tracks = new Array(tracksCount).fill().map( t => ({ right:0, left: 0 }) );
```

Helping?